# Why is $? nil in RSpec (Outside of a Rails app)

Tags: ruby, rspec

I have a Rails app that uses `$?.exitstatus` in the tests, and it works just fine.

I am trying to make a gem that uses `$?.exitstatus` in the tests, but I am receiving:

```
NoMethodError:
   undefined method `exitstatus' for nil:NilClass
```

Here's are two sample files that I created to reproduce the issue:

#### superman.rb

```
class Superman
  def self.execute(command)
    `#{command}`
  ensure
    puts $?.exitstatus
  end
end
```

#### my_spec.rb

```
describe Superman do
  it 'should execute' do
    expect(Superman).to receive(:execute).and_return(1)
    expect($?.exitstatus).to be 0
  end 
end
```

**Why can I use `$?` inside my Rails specs, but not in plain ruby? Is there something I need to require?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$?` returns the `Process::Status` of the last child process to execute.  If no child process has been executed, you will get `nil`.

In this case, because you are not actually calling `Superman.execute`, there is no child process status to return.  Additionally, even if you add `Superman.execute("ls")` to your spec, you've stubbed it above and the same still holds true.

Try:

```
describe Superman do
  it 'should execute' do
    # There's really no reason for this expect(..).to receive anyway
    # since it's pretty obvious it's going to get called since we're
    # calling it directly right below.
    expect(Superman).to receive(:execute).and_call_original
    Superman.execute("ls")
    expect($?.exitstatus).to eq(0)
  end
end
```

Yields:

```
rspec ./superman_spec.rb
0
.

Finished in 0.01054 seconds (files took 0.10346 seconds to load)
1 example, 0 failures
```